# How to return multiple views without being page reloaded?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc

> Blockquote

I have "Login" view and controller with multiple condition that any condition returns a view. but my "Login" controller is in just one view. so, I want to return conditions without being page refresh or reload. can someone help and provide on my code?
what should I change in the view? or what should i add?
COntroller code:

```
[HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public virtual async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string ReturnUrl = "")
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "لطفا فلید های * دار را کامل کنید.";
                return View("Login");
            }
            //اگرعدد ها را فارسی وارد کند آن ها رو به انگلیسی تبدیل می کنیم 
            var UserName = Helper.Helper.NumberFN_To_EN(model.UserName);
            var Password = Helper.Helper.NumberFN_To_EN(model.Password);

            // به دنبال کاربری با نام کاربر وارد شده میگردیم
            var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(UserName).ConfigureAwait(false);
            var isUserPasswordCorrect = false;
            // اگر کاربر وجود داشت
            if (user != null)
            {
                isUserPasswordCorrect = await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, Password).ConfigureAwait(false);
                // اگر کاربر رمزش  را درست وارد کرده بود
                if (isUserPasswordCorrect)
                {
                    // اگر کاربر غیر فعال کامل یا غیر فعال
                    if (user.IsDisabled)
                    {
                        ViewBag.ShowSupport = true;
                        ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "حساب کاربری شما غیرفعال می‌باشد لطفا با پشتیبان سایت در تماس باشید";
                        return View();
                    }
                    // اگر هیچ نقشی نداشت
                    // جلوی ورود او را میگیریم
                    if (!user.Roles.Any())
                    {
                        ViewBag.ShowSupport = true;
                        ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "کاربر گرامی! شما در سیستم هیچ پستی ندارید";
                        return View();
                    }
                }
            }
            var result = SignInStatus.Failure;
            if (user != null)
            {
                // آیا کاربر رمز عبورش را درست وارد کرده است ؟
                if (isUserPasswordCorrect)
                {
                    // عملیات لاگین را انجام میدهیم
                    result = await _signInManager
                                   .PasswordSignInAsync(UserName, Password, true, true)
                                   .ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
            }
            // نتیجه عملیات لاگین
            switch (result)
            {
                // اگر ورود موفقیت آمیز بود
                case SignInStatus.Success:
                    //اطلاعات لازم رو میگیریم و یه لاگ برای کاربر ثبت میشود 
                    _logService.Add(new Log { UserId = user.Id, IP = Request.UserHostAddress, LogType = LogType.Login, CreatedDate = DateTime.Now });
                    _uow.SaveAllChanges();
                    var roleuser = await _applicationRoleManager.FindByIdAsync(user.Roles.SingleOrDefault().RoleId).ConfigureAwait(false);

                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ReturnUrl))
                    {
                        ReturnUrl = AuthenticationHelper.GetDashboardForRole(roleuser.Name);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (!Url.IsLocalUrl(ReturnUrl))
                        {
                            ReturnUrl = AuthenticationHelper.GetDashboardForRole(roleuser.Name);
                        }
                    }

                    return Redirect(ReturnUrl);
                // اگر اکانت قفل شده است
                case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                    // زمان رفع محدودیت کاربر برای ورود
                    // زمان خروجی
                    // UTC
                    // است پس آن را به تاریخ عادی تبدیل می کینم
                    var theTimeOfUnBanUser = user.LockoutEndDateUtc.Value.UtcToLocalTime().ToString("HH:mm:ss");
                    ViewBag.ShowSupport = true;
                    ViewBag.ErrorMessage = $"حساب کاربری شما قفل شده است، لطفا بعد از ساعت {theTimeOfUnBanUser} دوباره تلاش نمایید";
                    return View();
                // اگر نام کاربری یا رمز عبور اشتباه است
                case SignInStatus.Failure:
                default:
                    // اگر نام کاربری وارد شده صحیح بود
                    if (user != null)
                    {
                        // تعداد حداکثر تلاش برای ورود ناموفق
                        var maxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = _userManager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout;
                        // تعداد ورود های ناموفق کاربر جاری
                        var accessFailedCount = await _userManager.GetAccessFailedCountAsync(user.Id).ConfigureAwait(false);
                        // تعداد تلاش مانده برای ورود
                        var numberOfAttemptsLeft = maxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout - accessFailedCount;

                        ViewBag.ShowSupport = true;
                        ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "رمز عبور اشتباه است" + System.Environment.NewLine + $"تعداد دفعات تلاش مجدد برای ورود {numberOfAttemptsLeft} بار";
                        return View();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ViewBag.ShowSupport = true;
                        ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "نام کاربری یا رمز عبور صحیح نمی باشد";
                        return View();
                    }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Search in google; "ajax partial view mvc"

Answer (score 0):

you have to use ajax call and send some json to client from server and then make decision base on json props like IsSuccess, Message, DefaultPageUrl and ....
this can help you : https://www.infinetsoft.com/Post/How-to-implement-Login-using-Ajax-in-asp-net-mvc/2469